# How to get the list of clients connected to an NFS server within a local network?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have an NFS server with folder permissions as follows. There are 50 clients which need to connect to this server within the same network. I would like to know what's the command to lookup which are the clients accessing this server from the server.

NFS Server configuration file looks like this.

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/exports
/home/guests    *(rw,sync)
/india          *(rw,sync)
```

Below are the  list of shared folders

```
[root@server ~]# showmount -e
Export list for server.sanith.com:
/india       *
/home/guests *
```

For testing purpose I have now connected one client to the server. Below output is from the "client2" machine.

```
[root@client2 ~]# showmount -e 192.168.1.10
Export list for 192.168.1.10:
/india       *
/home/guests *
[root@client2 ~]# mount -t nfs 192.168.1.10:/india /test
[root@client2 ~]# mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
192.168.1.10:/india on /test type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.10,clientaddr=192.168.1.12)
```

I tried using `showmount -a` and `showmount -d` but not sure what am missing which's not list the client machines connected.

```
[root@server ~]# showmount -a
All mount points on server.sanith.com:
[root@server ~]# man showmount
[root@server ~]# showmount -d
Directories on server.sanith.com:
[root@server ~]# netstat -an | grep 192.168.1.10:2048
[root@server ~]# netstat -an | grep 192.168.1.10:2049
[root@server ~]# cat /var/lib/nfs/rmtab
[root@server ~]#
```

Note : The firewall is disabled on the server temporarily during this testing.
Please advise.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find connected NFS clients by running the following on the NFS server:

```
netstat | grep :nfs
```

Comment: This did not work on CentOS 6.x for me.  I had to do this:

`sudo netstat -a | grep nfs`

Comment: To avoid delays, use netstat -n for "not resolve names" and search for :843 (default port) instead of :nfs

Comment: Isn't the default port 2049?

Answer (score 10):

Since Linux kernel 5.3 you can use special directory called `/proc/fs/nfsd/clients`.

You can check Kernel version by `uname -r` command

Answer (score 7):

Since `netstat` is not always available for it is to be replaced by `ss` you also might use

`ss -a|grep nfs`

Answer (score 5):

NFS works over both UDP and TCP, only open TCP connections will show in `netstat` or `ss`. Also, as a distributed filesystem, it has (historically) had its fair share of [problems](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2006/ols2006v2-pages-59-72.pdf)<sup>PDF</sup> (state, cache, locking, notifications, security — some of which have solutions through extra RPC features, e.g. `rpc.statd`).

On a Linux NFS server (see `man rpc.mountd`) the client mount/unmount requests are recorded in `/var/lib/nfs/rmtab`, just like `/etc/mtab`, sothe answer should be:

```
cat /var/lib/nfs/rmtab
```

If it's empty, then you either have a problem with `rpc.mountd` (so you should check the RPC services running), or all the clients are NFSv4 which doesn't use this feature.

On versions I've checked `rmtab` is presented as:

```
10.1.2.0/24:/path/to/export1:0x000...flags
10.1.2.10:/path/to/export1:0x0000...flags
10.1.2.22:/path/to/export1:0x0000...flags
10.1.2.0/24:/path/to/export2:0x000...flags
10.1.2.22:/path/to/export2:0x0000...flags
10.1.2.99:/path/to/export2:0x0000...flags
```

i.e., each mount point is listed, followed by the clients using it.

Note the caveat in the man page:

> However, this file is mostly ornamental. One, the client  can  continue to  use  the file handle even after calling rpc.mountd's UMOUNT procedure. And two, if a client reboots without  notifying  rpc.mountd, a stale entry will remain in rmtab.

The `/proc/fs/nfsd/client` approach (@Vsevolod Gromov's answer) in newer kernels should be better in this respect, but because it only [supports NFSv4 clients](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-fsdevel/1557969619-17157-1-git-send-email-bfields@redhat.com/) which should be better behaved.

Answer (score 2):

```
netstat -a | grep nfs
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.